# Visited the site for 30 consecutive days? Not me

Tags: discussion, login, consecutive-days

I have just received a notification saying that I have earned a badge for having logged in for 30 consecutive days. The fact is, I haven't done that. Is there something weird going on? Is there a way I can see an access log or something?

This has not happened with other Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: The days are measured in UTC, is it possible while you haven't visited the site daily in your timezone you might have in UTC?

Comment: I've tried to get this badge on purpose, and since I come here every day anyway I didn't think it would be hard. Not so. The UTC timezone has stung me several times, leaving a gap in my visits as far as the server is concerned even though, from my perspective, I **did** come here *every. single. day*. IMO, the badge should be from the client's timezone.

Comment: @Chris Maybe so, but I feel like that would probably be vulnerable to exploitation...

Comment: @Stephan yep, I am sure about that. I might have visited the site maybe 5 times in the month. Maybe a forgotten open tab might have caused this?

Comment: @user1301428 You have to do something more than refresh the page for it to register as a visit (i.e. upvote a question/answer, comment, etc.)

Comment: @AstroCB Then I have no explanation for this. Who should I contact to look into this?

Comment: @user1301428 Try [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/contact) or team@stackoverflow.com

Comment: Do you use the SE Android app? I believe that using this app counts as site visit.

Comment: @AstroCB actually yes. But why didn't this happen on every other SE site?

Comment: @user1301428 Visits are measured on a per-site basis; if you look on your profile for each site, it will tell you how many consecutive visits you have.

Comment: @AstroCB right, what I meant was, if the Android app is the culprit, why haven't I earned the same badge on all the other SE sites at the same time?

Comment: @user1301428 The app also registers visits on a per-site basis based on the sections you go to and the questions you're active on.

Comment: @AstroCB Still strange, since I use the app maybe two or three times a month (if at all). I will wait for a response from the SO team, let's see what they have to say.

Comment: @EnmosProje [Yes, it does.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/193269/254778)

Comment: @EnmosProje yes sorry, wrong reply :P

Comment: @Chris Perhaps an algorithm that's timezone-independent— something like: the maximum time from one visit to the next must be no more than 24 hours, and the time between the first day and the 30th day must be at most `(30+1)*24` hours.  We'd lose the profile visited-calendar, but it would be fairer scoring.

Comment: Are you using Chrome? Start page display most frequent sited and refreshes them to show you proper thumbnail.

Comment: Same thing happened to me. I was on vacation a few days without my laptop. This is not an app/preview/timezone thing. I suspect that since I never log out of SO it just counts me as logged in. Maybe at some point people get automatically logged out after some period of inactivity, but that period is longer than a few days.

Comment: @AstroCB Just an observation: I think using the app doesn't count as a visit to all your accounts. I can't lay my finger on the exact logic behind it but what I've seen is that when I visit an account using the app just one or two of my accounts gain a visit count.

Comment: @EnmosProje The app is divided into sections for each exchange, so it only counts as visits to the ones that you actually, well, *visit*, by upvoting or viewing a couple of questions. As the [answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191781/last-seen-not-updating-when-using-android-app/193269#193269) said, viewing the feed won't do you any good.

Comment: @mleko I don't think that would do it because it takes more than visiting the front page to count as a visit.

Comment: @AstroCB that is wrong. I received confirmation from the SO Team that it is sufficient to read a page to count a visit, you don't need to do any action.

Comment: @user1301428 Well, then they must [have lied to us](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191781/last-seen-not-updating-when-using-android-app/193269#193269)...

Comment: See my answer for a better explanation :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After receiving the access logs from the SO Team and seeing that there was no suspect activity in there (sorry @Benjamin Gruenbaum), I was also told that it is sufficient to **read** a page (and do something more, even though I wasn't given more details to avoid people trying to play unfair) to make it count as a visit.

In my case this probably happened because of a SO tab that I had left open in my browser, which would load every day when I turned on my PC, and for using the Android app, probably a combination of the two.

Comment: Actually, i also do use SO in a browser tab, but it always breaks my visits, even if i check it every day... I really dont understand why it always breaks...

Answer (score 27):

If you go to your [main user profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1301428/user1301428), you can see that there is a `visited` section, which is a private field:

[image]

If you click on the text in that section, it will give you a calendar that shows the days that you visited SO in green and days that you didn't in white:

[image]

Comment: Ok, but this does not tell me anything more than I already know, i.e. that I have visited the site every day for the past 30 days. I would like to see when and where the connections have been made.

Comment: @user1301428 someone else is using your account.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum lol I love how confident you sound XD That would be weird, there has been no strange activity for 30 days.

Comment: @user1301428 Just admit that you're a SO junkie. It's ok. Alternatively, your cat (or wife) might have been pressing random keys because they feel so clicky. Or, some browser prefetch thing might be at fault. Think of something you have installed that might be accessing SO, such as RSS reader, webpage thumbnail generation, etc.

Comment: Mine says *1459 days, 907 consecutive*. Is there a badge for 1k consecutive days? I hope so.

Comment: @ta.speot.is: No, [there isn't](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges)  :( I'm at "465 days, 367 consecutive".

Comment: That calendar pop-up is _depressing_.

Comment: @0x7fffffff: I'm not sure if that's true. In the past, I've asked Stack Exchange (via an email to team@) to have the list of IPs that accessed my account. They were given to me after a simple verification process.

Comment: @AmalMurali I stand corrected. I guess that's the answer then.

Comment: There's no badge @ta.speot.is... though [Bill and VonC have been competing for a while now](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/122976/179419)

Comment: @ta.speot.is, didn't you receive a [couple of pop ups](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/157449/185667)?

Answer (score 3):

It is possible that you left your account signed in at a different computer or device. Which is used by someone to search on google and find answers on StackOverflow. So, the first thing to do is to confirm that you have not left your account logged in anywhere else.

Secondly, if you feel its been compromised, change your password, check your account page for any unusual activity and [report it to SE](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/contact).

Thirdly, check your computer for virus and worms.

Alternatively, you might have bookmarked stackoverflow and added it to your speed dial (or main screen) where it is generating thumbnails of the websites which are bookmarked. An error could lead to thumbnail generation everyday. Check if you have not install any such add-on
[image]

Comment: I realized that I had left a stackoverflow tab open on my laptop, but apparently that should not count as activity. That (and the Android app) are the only places where I am logged in. No strange activity in my account and no worms or viruses on the laptop. Also, I have already changed my password, just in case.

Comment: Did you left the tab open for 30 days?

Comment: Easily so, yes since I use the laptop pretty much every day.